# iOS 7 navigationBar and iOS 6 navigationBar show different background image

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I try to set background image to navigationBar I use blow code

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pp_Header.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

My image height is 120px

In iOS6 navigationBar height 120px but in iOS7 shows only 68px but i need to show 120px,

similarly Tool bar also having same problem

```
[pad_por_Toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_bottom.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

how to solve this ?

Comment: Check this one : http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: still I cant change iOS 7 navigationBar height